# Hibernate - between dates not working

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have a problem with *BETWEEN* date1 and date2.

For example: 2016-09-25 - 2016-09-25. I want to show all records for one day (2016-09-25). But to be able to view these records, I have to select 2016-09-25 - 2016-09-26, and 2016-09-27 if I want the records for 26th.

How should my SQL query look like?

Comment: My guess, the field you are `BETWEEN`ing is a type that hold a time component; if that is the case try `BETWEEN '2016-09-25 00:00:00' AND '2016-09-25 23:59:59'`.

Comment: I convert the filed and the database column to @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE),  and DATE respectively.. and still doesn't work..

Comment: btw.. It works with - BETWEEN '2016-09-25 00:00:00' AND '2016-09-25 23:59:59', even after i change the type of columns ??

Comment: I am not familiar with that `@Temporal` stuff, guessing it is a part of Hibernate; but if adding the time components to the range bounds works, the server must still be seeing a time component on the field. Even if the `Temporal` ended up working something like `CAST(field AS DATE)` this would still be a better condition (as it does not rely on having to convert the field value for every row in the table to make the comparison, and can rely on indexes if present).

Comment: Question is not clear for better understanding.

Comment: column type is DATE or DATETIME? If are DATETIME  2016-09-25 means  2016-09-25 00:00:00 so there are no items between 2016-09-25 00:00:00 and 2016-09-25 00:00:00 (it's a point in time), you need to do between 2016-09-25 00:00:00 and 2016-09-26 00:00:00 (midnight next day, which is the end of the previous day)

Answer (score 0):

`BETWEEN` is inclusive so `BETWEEN 2016-09-25 AND 2016-09-25` is equal to `= 2016-09-25`
Why it is not working for you is because your column has not only date but time as well. So you have data with date lets say `2016-09-25 10:23:42` this will not work - `2016-09-25` is equal to `2016-09-25 00:00:00`. You have to either query like `DATE(column) BETWEEN 2016-09-25 AND 2016-09-25` to ignore time, or `BETWEEN 2016-09-25 00:00:00 AND 2016-09-25 23:59:59`